# Does Oracle SQL Developer refresh when you launch it?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I've just run a couple of queries where I forgot to click on the blue 'refresh' button when I launched Oracle SQL Developer.

But I was wondering whether it actually refreshes anyway, when you actually launch it?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: 'no.'

But first, let's share with folks with the 'blue refresh button' you mention in your question.

[image]

What does this button do?

It re-executes the query that the resultset is tied to, in this case

```
select * from employees
```

When you restart/re-open SQL Developer it does not even connect to any databases, much less re-execute any queries automatically.

What you might see is a .SQL file re-opened as you had it open when you closed the application from your last session. But no database work will happen until you hit the 'Connect' button.

*Disclaimer: I work for Oracle and am the product manager for SQL Developer.*

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, Jeff. If I clicked on the refresh button in Oracle SQL Developer once, then had to restart my laptop, I assume that I wouldn't have to click refresh again, when I log back in (a few mins later) to run other queries, right?

Comment: Hi @thatjeffsmith do you know if there's a way to automate the refreshing of a database, so that it gets automatically refreshed everyday at a specific time?